# Python2.7 - Interpreter syntax error after installing Python3

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

When I'm trying to write anything on the python27 interpreter, I'm getting syntax error, no matter what I'm typing (Not just `print`, literally anything). Couldn't find anyone else experiencing the same issue, so no clue why this is happening.

I've recently installed Python3 and PyCharm, but I still want to use python27 for some legacy code I have. The problem started to happen after I installed Python3 and PyCharm (Not sure if PyCharm may be related or not).

my OS is Windows10 x64.
Any ideas anyone?

Python27:
[image: Python27]

Python3:

[image: Python3]

Comment: Can you reproduce on the command line with something like `python.exe -c 'print "Test"'`? (Not sure exactly what the syntax is going to look like on Windows.)

Comment: Try rebooting. Last time I saw something like this, it turned out to be an issue with a C library getting updated, and a reboot fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce this perfectly by using a non-break space unicode character as the last character:

```
Python 2.7.16 (default, Apr 11 2019, 01:11:37) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible FreeBSD Clang 6.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_600/final 326565)] on freebsd11
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print "Test" 
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print "Test" 
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> import os 
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    import os 
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> 111 
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    111 
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

When I copy/paste that into IPython based on python 3, it shows up:

```
In [1]: test = 'print "Test" '                                                                           
Out[1]: 'print "Test"\xa0'

In [2]: import unicodedata

In [3]: unicodedata.name(test[-1])                                                                           
Out[3]: 'NO-BREAK SPACE'
```

I expect the same to happen with any space-like unicode character.

When typing code into Python, use <kbd>End</kbd> to go to the end of the line, and then one or more <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to remove any extra whitespace, *before* you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. If your cursor moves when you press <kbd>End</kbd>, that would confirm the issue.

If not, then maybe it is whatever the terminal program sends to Python when you press `Enter`.

I would advise to just remove python 2.7 and port any remaining 2.7 specific code to python 3.

**Edit** Since you still need Python 2, I would suggest to try running a python 2 script. If that works, the problem is probably with the terminal setup (like text encoding, line feed etc.) being different than what Python 2 expects. If scripts work, try one of the many different terminal programs available for ms-windows.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the case for me it seems.. I have any "extra" whitespace letters if i press the `End` key. But interesting thought.

Also, for Python3 I don't seem to have any issues, it only occurs on python27 (Not using Ipython for either)

Comment: Python 3 probably just ignores more kinds of whitespace.

Comment: Can it be somehow related though to the installation of python3? Because this is when it started to happen

Comment: I don't really see how. Both installations seem to have their own installation directory, so they should not interfere. Unless you've got heaps of legacy code, just remove python 2.7. It is past its prime.

Comment: I'm working with a lot of legacy code that will not be converted to python3 any time soon. Is there still anything possible to do, to work with previous python2 interpreter? Still couldn't fix the problem